# VersionFromLanguage module crashes on Sitecore 8.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

One of our clients has recently upgraded their sitecore from 7.0 to 8.0 and they used to work with [VersionFromLanguage module](https://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/sitecore/quickly-create-new-language-versions-on-your-sitecore-cms/) to duplicate same content to multiple languages. But after upgrade, the content editor crashes with following error if the module gets activated (by enabling its config file):

```
Could not load type 'Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.WebEditCommand' from assembly 'Sitecore.Client, Version=8.0.5245.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I was thinking about better techniques such as language fallback in long term but is there any quick fix to this module? (It must be something about the way buttons get registered on SPEAK UI comparing to older shell API, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to switch to Sheer UI. 
  In Sitecore 8, the Experience editor by default uses SPEAK for the ribbon.
 To use old Sheer UI (if is an option for you ) you need to modify Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config

```
<pageextenders>
<!-- Uncomment the page extenders below and comment the   "Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.PageExtender.RibbonPageExtender" to switch to old SheerUI-based Experience Editor ribbon. -->
<pageextender type="Sitecore.Layouts.PageExtenders.PreviewPageExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
<pageextender type="Sitecore.Layouts.PageExtenders.WebEditPageExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
<pageextender type="Sitecore.Layouts.PageExtenders.DebuggerPageExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />

<pageextender type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Preview.SimulatedDevicePreview.PageExtenders.PreviewExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />

<!-- Page extender for SPEAK-based Experience Editor ribbon. -->
<!--<pageextender type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.PageExtender.RibbonPageExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon" />-->
 </pageextenders>
```

On next links you will find information about how to customize ribbons in Sitecore 8 and what steps you need to follow to fix your issues into Sitecore 8.

http://www.programmingbynumbers.com/2015/01/31/creating-a-new-experience-editor-button-in-sitecore-8/
       https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/the_editing_tools/customize_the_experience_editor_ribbon